# Counter each jquery

Tags: jquery, split, each

My counter does not work, does someone know why?

```
 var idVinyl = 1;
    $(this.split(/<img.+?>/)).each(function()
        {
                $("#vinyl" + idVinyl +" p").html(this + " ");
                idVinyl++;
                console.log("test " + idVinyl+": " + this);
            }
        });
```

Comment: What is not working? And what is `this`?

Comment: It also looks like you have an extra `}`.

Comment: If `.each()` loops throught the array/object, why you don't use `.length()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside [jQuery.each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) you don't need any counter because it's provide counter to you by default :

```
$(this.split(/<img.+?>/)).each(function (index, value) {
    $("#vinyl" + index + " p").html(this + " ");
    console.log("test " + (index + 1) + ": " + this);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Jquery each already gives you an index value.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

Any reason why you are making your own?

```
$(this.split(/<img.+?>/)).each(function(index, value){
...
});
```

Comment: You are right.  My original answer was correct, I just second guessed myself.  Jquery allows arrays to be wrapped.

Answer (score 0):

A vague description of your problem, but I assume that

```
this.split(/<img.+?>/))
```

returns an array and not a jQuery object, you need to pass it to jQuery's each method like this:

```
var arr = this.split(/<img.+?>/));

$.each(arr, function(){
    console.log(this);
});
```